# PaypalMobile throws error on Authorize intent

Tags: ios, swift, paypal-sandbox, paypal-mobile-sdk

I am using `PayPalMobileSDK` for Single Payment Processing.
When ever i use the intent of payment to **Sale** it works perfectly, but when i change the intent to **Authorize**

I am using the sample-Swift code provided with SDK and testing in `Sandbox Environment`.

Code with **Sale** intent

```
let payment = PayPalPayment(amount: total, currencyCode: "USD", shortDescription: "Hipster Clothing", intent: .sale)

payment.items = items
payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails
```

Code with **Authorize** intent

```
let payment = PayPalPayment(amount: total, currencyCode: "USD", shortDescription: "Hipster Clothing", intent: .authorize)

payment.items = items
payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also facing this issue 
i have seen this issue related to your paypal account 
use a different account or you can configure the setting of paypal.
you will not allowed to login if there is issue in your account details. 
let me know if you have any problem

Comment: Some how you're answer is correct but there are still few misleads in your answer. Below statement in your answer is not correct.
if your account setting are correct than you will get two things in response PAyment ID and Authorization ID.
But thanks you save me by telling me to re configure my account.